# Staging step in Data Warehousing?

Tags: mongodb, data-warehouse, data-cleaning, data-scrubbing, nosql

How do usually people perform staging step in Data warehousing??

I have to do a similar task and I am not sure if using a NoSQL Database would be a good option for data integration purposes and how much easy and efficient would it be to perform data cleansing and scrubbing

Has someone done some work in this area?

Please let me know

Apologies for a generic question, but didn't come up with a better place to ask such question than SO

Thank you

Comment: What is your source data? I am not familiar with NoSQL databases at the moment. But I guess that Your source data is some RDBMS or some other type of tabular data. If so, why even evaluating NoSQL as an option?

Answer (score 1):

For data scrubbing and ETL you want the richest query facilities you can get, which is not generally regarded as a strength of NoSQL databases.  In most cases you're probably better off with a conventional RDBMS platform for a data warehouse system.

Answer (score 0):

For Staging area you might need a strong RDBMS platform. I have used Teradata for it and its one of the best RDBMS available till now as it allows parallel execution of queries and it has very high performance.